# sql server transactional replication high latency

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am new to system and we have database of size around 2TB and its has been set up for replication. there are 4 subscriber to it. Tables (articles) of database has been divided into 14 publishers. Issue sometime we face high latency on server with hundreds of thousands of undistributed command

I am new to sql replication so what should i check. I mean i want to check from which tables(articles) highest number of commands pending from publisher to distributor and from distributor to subscriber .where to check i mean which system tables or stored procedures to check.

As i found replication monitor to be insufficient.

I know its tea spoon feeding but as i am new to sql server replication

Comment: How often does the data change on the source tables? 100,000s of undistributed commands should only happen if the Publication is completely down for some reason or there are tons of data changes on the source database that Replication isn't keeping up with (which then there is likely a latency issue).

Comment: it happens frequently